# Problem with javascript in Blackberry (OS 4.6) native browser

Tags: browser, blackberry, innerhtml

When call to this ajax function is repeated a second time, response is appended (not replaced), to info id. 
This occurs both when I use innerHTML and XUI shortcut function.  Code works properly on IE and Mozilla desktop.

```
 function ajax_call()
 {
    var full_date = document.getElementById('from_date').value;             
    x$('#status').xhr('myPgm.pgm?userid=/%userid%/&calDate=' +full_date,
    function(){                 
        //document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        x$('#info').html(this.responseText);                
     }
   ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does ajax call return?  Is that doubled up?

Comment: on IE and Mozilla, I can see see response with firebug & I get correct response. With blackberry I have no visibility, but I have no reason to believe that response would be any different. Problem seems to be with innerHTML function.